# react.js apollo useQuery Invalid hook call,

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm trying to wrap my head around using react and apollo graphql,

but I'm getting `Invalid hook call` and I'm not sure why, I think I'm calling inside a component.

here's my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo'
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'

import './App.css'

const GET_POLLS = gql`
{
  insurances {
    user {
      name
    }
    insurable {
      address_line1
      address_line2
      postcode
      town
    }
  }
}
`

function App() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_POLLS)

  if (loading) {return (
      <div>Loading</div>
      )}
  if (error) {return (
      <div>Error :  ${error.message}</div>
      )}

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <header className='header'>
        <h1 className='name'>Insurances API</h1>
      </header>
      <main className='main'>
         <p>here goes the data</p>

      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

any ideas?

### update

if I comment out the `useQuery` call and set a `const state = useState();` instead the component works,

it seems to be a problem related to `useQuery`

### update 2

I switched to use `@apollo/client` instead, but I'm getting the very same problem.

here's my full code:

index.js

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider
} from "@apollo/client";

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const client = new ApolloClient({ 
  link:  'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache() 
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    header
    <App />
    footer
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

import './App.css'

const GET_INSURANCES = gql`
  query GetExchangeRates {
    rates(currency: "USD") {
      currency
      rate
    }
  }
`;

function App() {
  const state = useState(1);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_INSURANCES);
  if (loading) return <div>Loading</div>
  if (error) return <div>Error :  ${error.message}</div>

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <header className='header'>
        <h1 className='name'>Insurances API</h1>
      </header>
      <main className='main'>
         <p>here goes the data {data}</p>
         <p>...{state}...</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

### update 3

here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "insurance-service",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "graphql": "^16.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "standard": "^16.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

Comment: react-apollo is deprecated and there is [unresolved issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3454)  about this. Is using `@apollo/client` instead an option for you?

Comment: I see, didn't know that, my project is greenfield I can use whatever, will try it, thanks

Comment: I updated to @apollo/client, but getting the very same error in `useQuery`

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`, I'm not able to reproduce this error with the same code you have

Comment: added package.json, thanks